# PDF form does not get filled by application

Tags: laravel, pdf, xfa, acrofields

I got a problem regarding the fillings of pdf-forms. 
I wrote a code in laravel to fill previously defined fields in my pdf form while using https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk . At first it worked very well with my pdf. Now I made a new pdf but here it is not working. I get the error message: "Warning: input PDF is not an acroform, so its fields were not filled." So I thought there had to be some xfa forms in my pdf but I checked it online and every test says that there are no xfa forms inside. Now I'm wondering is there a third type of forms in pdf I don't know or did anybody encounter similar problems maybe while working with this pdftk plugin ?

Like I said with my first pdf It worked quite good and I didn't change the way of creating the pdf. Just with the new one it is not working anymore and I really don't know why. I tried some online tools to remove xfa forms but it keeps telling me that there are no such forms in my pdf.

These are the codefragments regarding the initialising of the pdf and the returning of the error message displayed above.

```
$pdf = new Pdf(asset('pdf/Angebot_new.pdf'), [
            'command' => public_path('PDFtk/bin/pdftk.exe'),
            'useExec' => true,
        ]);


$error = "No Error";
        if (!$pdf->send('my.pdf')) {
            $error = $pdf->getError();
        }
        return $error;
```

Comment: Address you sure your pdf actually dies contain an acroform form definition?

Comment: I got forms inside my pdf with fields which got names. This is all I really now, is there a way to check the "format" of my forms   or form fields? To inspect it and I get to know what kind of form/field is it ?

Comment: Can you share the pdf?